# Any way to get AquaTerm to tile automatically from Gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I know how to set the window size for Aquaterm from Gnuplot, but is there a way to get AquaTerm to tile multiple windows automatically, when writing commands in Gnuplot?

(BTW, just a simple YES or NO answer is fine for me, to stop me trying…  I've looked online quite a bit, but there's very little info about AquaTerm.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the terminal an integer number to open up a new window. Don't know if that's automatic enough:

```
set terminal aqua
plot x
set terminal aqua 1
plot x**2
...
```

If you don't want to specify the terminal explicitely, you can use the GPVAL_TERM variable:

```
plot x
set terminal GPVAL_TERM 1
plot x**2
...
```

This should work with all interactive terminals (`x11`, `aqua`, `wxt` and `qt`).

Comment: Thanks Christoph.  I found out how to do this already - in fact you answered a question of mine about this on Stack Overflow!  However, this cascades the windows, rather than tiling them.  To be honest though, it isn't difficult to then get them to tile in AquaTerm - there is a keyboard shortcut.  So, I'm  going to accept this answer...